# Parse content from CMS and add dynamic IDs that tie to ReactJS state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

I have a simple react component that makes a call to get content from a CMS:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: '/cms/content',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            this.setState({data: data})
        }.bind(this)
    });
};
render(){
    if(this.state && this.state.data)
    {
            return (
                 <div>{this.state.data.content}</div>      
                );
    }
    return (
            <div>
                Loading....
            </div>
       );    
    };
```

};

When the content comes back from the CMS it may have 1 to many 'placeholders' that will need to be replaced with a value from a different call.

> **Sample Content:** 'This is content from the CMS and my name is {{firstName}} {{lastName}}'

I need to extract all the {{}} tags and send them to a different REST service to get their associated values.

The response from that service call will be simple key value pairs in JSON format.

> **Example response** {
>   "firstName":"john",
>   "lastName":"smith"
>   }

What I would like to do is get the initial content, display it without the embedded keys, use those keys for a second call to get the values associated to the keys and when that service call comes back....replace the embedded keys with the values from the second call.

Or another way to show what I am trying to accomplish

Service 1 response:

> Hello my name is: {{first}} {{last}}

Display:

> Hello my name is:

Call second service with and array of values ["first","last"]

When the 2nd service call comes back re-render with

> Hello my name is John Smith.

One crucial factor is I will not know what the embedded keys are or if any even exist. I will only know the pattern in which they will be in. ie: {{key}}. So I will have to be able to search the content for their existence and process accordingly if they do exist.

Comment: from first request are you getting JSON?

Comment: The initial service call for content will return JSON.